# Properly expose applications in Kubernetes with an ingress

Tags: kubernetes, dns, load-balancing, bare-metal, cert-manager

I'm fairly new to Kubernetes and having some problems understanding some things.

I'm setting up a cluster on Hetzner Cloud for client applications. In order to make the ingresses of the applications work, I deployed Hetzner Cloud Controller Manager. My question is, how do I expose the applications so i can access them from the outside on client1.**cluster.example.com**, client2.**cluster.example.com**, etc...
The Hetzner loadbalancer that the cloud control manager manages, forwards incoming requests from ports 443 (on the loadbalancer) to 30500 (on the ingress controller) and 80 to 30379.

1. Is this possible?
2. If so, do i need to set up a DNS record for *.**cluster.example.com**?
3. How do i do this with ssl certificates, how does this work?

any help will be appreciated
Thank you :)

I tried searching for these things on the internet, but since my lack of experience I couldn't find out whether the situations were applicable to my situation.

Answer (score 1):

First you create a service for your application. You use the default service type (ClusterIP).

Then you create an ingres-ngnix service of type load balancer.

And you need to create some Ingress rules to make URL paths to the service of your application.

And you need to set the annotation for the Ingres nginx controller to your zone (for example fsn1).

If you are using cluster API provider hetzner from Syself (which I recommend), then the docs should guide you. Please create an issue if the docs are missing something.

(I work for Syself)